# How to fix incompatible pointer type sending?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

```
SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"Sprites"];
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"debri_%ld",(long)randomPiece];  
SKTexture *temp = [atlas textureNamed:imageName];
SKSpriteNode *debris = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:temp]; 
debris.position = position; 
[self addChild:debris];
```

I am getting warning in line "SKSpriteNode" I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: make ur question more clear @ericson ortega

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:]` accepts a string parameter, which is causing the error.  You want:

```
SKSpriteNode *debris = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:temp];
```

Comment: Also I keep on getting error with SKTexture not finding projectile_1. I am doing universal app here is my code:

Comment: @EricsonOrtega Ask a new question about that issue.

Comment: ETProjectileNode *projectile = [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"projectile_1"];
    projectile.position = position;
    projectile.name = @"Projectile";